# Best practice to handle object for useEffect deps array in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[The official beta doc](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#read-primitive-values-from-objects) says they recommend us to parse the object outside of useEffect to avoid unnecessary re-rendering. However, if there are a slew of properties in an object, parsing properties is not realistic.

What is the best way to handle props of object with many properties in React to avoid unnecessary re-rendering?

For example,

```
interface Props {
  obj: {
    property1: number;
    property2:{ val1: number };
    ...
    property100: number;
  };
}

// const { ... } = obj; // <- its not realistic to parse here cuz there are many properties 

const Component = ({ obj }: Props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    someFunc(obj) // someFunc takes obj as an argument
  }, [obj]) // <-  this causes unnecessary re-rendering
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official beta doc](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#read-primitive-values-from-objects), they say to read only the **necessary** information from the object.

So, if re-renders are only depending on a few properties, you can destruct the object and obtain the properties you want.

Else, if you know the properties you want to use to re-render the component, you can construct an array of them using a loop and use that array as the dependency array.

```js
const Component = ({ obj }: Props) {
  let deps = ['property1', 'property2', 'property52', 'property100'];
  deps = deps.map((key) => obj[key]);

  useEffect(() => {
    someFunc(obj)
  }, deps)
}
```

Comment: only for primitives though (property2 is an object)